# is it possible to generate java class file with hibernate annotation from mysql table in eclispe

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, annotations

I have mysql table with various fields.

Is it possible to automatic generate java file in eclispe with mapping of mysql table columns with java fields  and getters and setters

Comment: you mean just the bean? or the whole db-wrapper?

Comment: just the bean or is more possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Hibernate Tools](http://www.jboss.org/tools/download/)

**EDIT** :

Refer [Hibernate Tools Reference Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/3.0.0.CR1/en/hibernatetools/html_single/index.html).

The important step is

- Create and configure `hibernate.reveng.xml`
- Open perspective `Hibernate` and configure `Hibernate Code Generation Configuration`
- Optional : Generate class file for `ReverseEngineering Strategy`, which is extends `DelegatingReverseEngineeringStrategy`

Comment: i have installed hibernate tools in eclispe , but how can i create the bean from mysql

Answer (score 2):

If I truly understand your question, then you may want to [use HibernateTools to generate Pojo classes](http://www.wikihow.com/Generate-Hibernate-Pojo-Classes-from-DB-Tables) from MySQL mappings.