# Is there anyway convert mysql table to Java class

Tags: java, mysql, class

I have many tables created  in mysql, Is there any way I convert fields in table to java class 
with the setter and getter and constructor?

Comment: question is not clear to me. Do you want to be able to create `entities` from the tables? What do you mean by `convert fields in table to java class withe setter and getter and constructor`?

Comment: This link might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245221/is-it-possible-to-generate-java-class-file-with-hibernate-annotation-from-mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is, it's called `JPA`. You can search online how to create basic setup for `JPA` project with `Hibernate` or many other available implementations of `JPA`.